# How to calculate a discriminant (b^2 - 4ac)in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

Hello everyone i'm new to assembly language and I can't figure out how to create a program to read in 3 16-bit integers a,b,c and then have it calculate the discriminant. (b^2-4ac)
Could anyone help me? 
So far I started off by trying to have the program multiply a and c together.

```
.data
Prompt  BYTE        "Enter a number ?" , 0
Message BYTE        "The discriminant is: ", 0
b       SDWORD  ?
a       SDWORD  ?
cc      SDWORD  ?
discriminant    SDWORD  ?
.code
main        PROC
mov edx, OFFSET Prompt          ; EDX must have the string's offset
    call    WriteString     ; Call the procedure to write a string
    call    ReadInt         ; Call the procedure to read an integer
    mov a, eax          ; The integer is read into AL, AX or EAX

    mov edx, OFFSET Prompt  ; Read another integer 
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadInt
    mov cc, eax

mov eax, a                          ; AL AX or EAX must have the
                    ;  multiplicand
    cdq             ; Clear the EDX register
    imul    cc          ; One operand - the multiplier
    mov Product, eax            ; The product is in AL, AX or EAX
```

Comment: Hi I actually don't know anything about C either. I'm starting out with assembly

Comment: [Oh, okay...](http://tinyurl.com/7zlwvql)

Answer (score 1):

You say you're using 16bit inputs, so a, b and c are expected to be 16bit integers. This will get you a 32bit signed result. With that, we can do:

```
; Get b ^ 2 into EBX
movsx eax, [WORD b] ; Sign extend b to 32bit
imul eax            ; Multiply
mov ebx, eax        ; Put the result into ebx

; Get 4ac into EAX
movsx eax, [WORD a] ; Sign extend a to 32bit
shl eax, 2          ; Multiply by 4
movsx ecx, [WORD c] ; Sign extend c to 32bit
imul ecx            ; EDX:EAX = 4 * a * c

; Subtract, the result is in EBX
sub ebx, eax
```

This is using 32bit operands because your example did. You can do an equivalent with 16bit operands, but will have to translate from DX:AX to 32bit if you did for a 32bit result. Note that depending on what assembler you are using, the syntax for `[WORD b]` may change. I have see some use `[WORD PTR b]` or just `WORD b` or the like.

Comment: Thank you for answering! However, I am not familiar with "shl" in shl eax, 2          ; Multiply by 4  Could you explain to me what that does and why I would need it in the program?

Comment: `SHL` means shift left. It basically takes all the bits of a value and moves them to the left however many times you specified and puts in 0s at the end. In this case, I am shifting the value twice to the left. Using 4bit cause it's short, this changes 1111 (which is -1) to 1100 (which is -4), or 1110 (which is -2) to 1000 (which is -8). `SHL` is a very fast operation on all x86s, whereas `IMUL` or `MUL` is not.

Comment: @andy Look up how binary numbers work and it will be clear that shifting all the bits left by one bit will multiply by 2. Think of normal decimal numbers (base 10), shifting left by one is multiplying by 10, binary is base 2 so shifting left by 1 is multiplying by 2.

Comment: @andy if that doesn't help consider shifting base 10 numbers left by 2 or 3. That is equivalent to multiplying by 10^2 or 10^3. Doing same shift left by 2 or 3 in base 2 is same as multiplying by 2^2 or 2^3